# quicksort: how do the choice of a pivot-element, input and the worst-case performance relate?

Tags: performance, algorithm, pivot, quicksort

From what I have understood reading posts on `quicksort` is that the choice of the pivot element hugely influences whether it runs with worst case performance for a given input or not.

I ask myself

1. does a `randomized` pivot element simply minimize (but not exclude) the chance of running in `n^2`
2. What condition(s) must the `input` meet given a `deterministic pivot element` like for example, always picking the first element as pivot so that `n^2` becomes reality.
3. How would I input so that worst-case performance becomes reality?

Others have given the example of an already sorted array be it in ascending or descending order as an extreme case.

I assume that this has to do with the `splitting procedure`, the pointers for `element < pivot` (and vice versa) and the way an unfavorable pivot element makes the splitting process more costly.

Could possibly someone show on a simple example like an `array` with `[1,2,3]` and pivot `[0]` how worst-case performance is met so that I can see how all this relates to one another.

Comment: O(n^2) is always a possible reality. You can only influence the chances for it occurring. And a "randomized pivot" is nonsense.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000964/quicksort-how-pivot-choosing-strategies-affect-the-overall-big-oh-behavior-of-q?rq=1

Comment: @HenkHolterman, there are approaches removing O(n^2) case completely by selecting good pivot always - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Comment: @maxim1000 - median-of-3 is more often used, a median-of medians does indeed prevent a worst-case pivot but at great cost. I'm not sure if that still outperforms ShellSort et al.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, a randomized pivot element simply makes the worst case unlikely.
2. A sufficient condition would be that the choice of the pivot, given an array of length *n*, always splits it into two arrays with one having length *O(1)*.
3. Assume you have some rule that at call *i*, the algorithm chooses the element of the array `values` at position *v(n, i)* as the pivot element (the example you gave is that *v(n, i) = 0* always, i.e., the algorithm always looks at the first element). Then set:

   values_0[v(n, 0)] = 0

   values_1[v(n, 1)] = 1

   values_2(v(n, 2)] = 2

   ....

where values_i is the array formed from the original array by omitting the elements at *v(n, j)* for *j < i*.

---

Regarding your example of [1, 2, 3] and pivot 0, to the best of my understanding, it is not well defined. You cannot obtain a full worst-case example using a fixed pivot element, as the recursion will never end.

Comment: No, a randomized pivot element simply changes for what input worst case happens. It's not a smaller set of permutations, just a different one.

Comment: However, very often an array to be sorted is already sorted or mostly sorted, so the situation where first or last element as pivot is the worst case or a really bad case happens quite often in practice.

Comment: What do you mean by length Theta(n) - Sorry I am (unfortunately not hat deep into the formalism yet. Can you please explain what it means or give an example? Thank you!

Comment: Theta(n) basically means "proportionally to". However, please see again point 2, as I have amended it to O(1), which basically means "a constant".